# Copper Tetrafluoroborate neutralisation/precipitation to reduce landfill

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I have 25L drums of Copper Tetrafluoroborate waste solution.

Can it be neutralised, precipitated in some way, to minimise the amount of waste that goes to landfill?

also, landfills prefer solid waste instead of liquid, so is there any cost effective way to reduce Copper Tetrafluoroborate to a solid?

Comment: This would seem to be a question of your local/state/national hazardous waste disposal laws, rules, and regulations (in addition to any institutional added requirements).

Comment: Depending on the quantity / concentration of the tetrafluoroborate, the time and equipment at your disposition, you might be interested in the following publication, where authors claim electrocoagulation and -decomposition with sacrificial electrodes of aluminum.  At least the abstract is accessible freely: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0043135419301629